# Chrome influences database backend counter?

Tags: google-chrome, spring-security

I am using Struts and Spring in my Java EE project. We have used Spring for user authentication. We have a logic like if you enter three consecutive wrong password then the user get locked. There is a counter in the database to count the login attempt.

Now the problem is when I use Chrome, and enters wrong password for the first time, the counter increases to 3 and the account gets locked.
For other browser it works ok.

I don't understand is there continuous three hit to the database by Chrome browser?

Just need help.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance as this probably won't answer your question directly.

You may want to try programs like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/r) to monitor your HTTP(S) traffic, in order to see what's going on? JFYI, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/r) might be a little harder to use, but is probably more powerful.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Cheers

Rich